# when we upload the media for first time in whatsapp it takes more time to upload and not the second time the same file?

Tags: java, android, whatsapp

when we upload the media for first time it takes more time to upload.And if we try to resend the same file to other friends the media will be sent in a second.How it is happening?

Comment: please elaborate  Your Question in Description

Answer (score 0):

When you first send media, it is uploaded from your mobile to server of whatsapp and remains there for some time period. So when you resend media to other friend, it doesn't require to upload again from your mobile as it is available on server. It goes from server to your friend.